# What do you mean by leaf components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

What do you mean by leaf components in React?

Do you mean highly reusable components?

I want a specific answer.

Comment: think of your app as a tree with branches and leafs, the components that are at the tip of the branches are leaf components.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Leaf component means that this component doesn't render any other component in the DOM. As for example,

Lets say, `componentA` renders `componentB` like this,

```
return <ComponentB />;
```

But `componentB` doesn't render any other component just some html elements like,

```
return <h1> This is componentB </h1>
```

We can say that componentB is a leaf component.

Comment: So, the host component is the very top component (oldest parent), isn't it?

Comment: The very top component is the root component.